# How do you call a variable from one function so you can use it another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right below, I have a monster of a code.

```
def battle(oppatk, oppdef, opphealth, oppeva, oppspe, oppname):
    var1 = 0
    while True:
        if var1 > 0:
            if speed > oppspe:
                playerattack(oppdef, playerattack(oppdef, opphealth, oppeva, oppname), oppeva, oppname)
                opponentattack(oppatk, opponentattack(oppatk, health, defense, oppname, evasion), defense, oppname, evasion)
            elif oppspe > speed:
                opponentattack(oppatk, opponentattack(oppatk, health, defense, oppname, evasion), defense, oppname, evasion)
                playerattack(oppdef, playerattack(oppdef, opphealth, oppeva, oppname), oppeva, oppname)
            else:
                aaa = random(0, 1)
                if aaa == 0:
                    opponentattack(oppatk, opponentattack(oppatk, health, defense, oppname, evasion), defense, oppname, evasion)
                    playerattack(oppdef, playerattack(oppdef, opphealth, oppeva, oppname), oppeva, oppname)
                else:
                    playerattack(oppdef, playerattack(oppdef, opphealth, oppeva, oppname), oppeva, oppname)
                    opponentattack(oppatk, opponentattack(oppatk, health, defense, oppname, evasion), defense, oppname, evasion)
```

Basically what happens is it goes through the playerattack and opponentattack functions depending on which is faster, the player or the opponent. However, when I call one of the functions for its returned value to use in its next run, it instead does a sort of sub-level code instead that has no real effect on the program. How would you write the code to avoid this?

Comment: Make sure that you are saving any updated values returned by your functions.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you are asking for. You can assign returned value to a variable: `ret_value = playerattack(...)`